# GDB - function "main" not defined

Tags: assembly, x86

This will be a pretty dumb mistake I think but I can't find a solution to the problem I'm having.

I'm trying to debug a simple program of mine in order to see if some new instructions (specifically the 'and'-instruction in this case) I'm learning are behaving as I expect.

As I compiled and linked my source code with "as -32 aufgabe4.s -o aufgabe4.o" and "ld -m aufgabe4.o -o aufgabe4 -e main", I'm now trying to debug the file with "gdb aufgabe4" but when I'm trying to set a breakpoint at main ("break main") I'm getting "Function "main" not defined." and I can't figure out why. Main is not only defined it's the entry point for the function.

```
.section .text
.section .data

.globl main
main:
    movl $1000000000, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    and %eax, %ebx
    subl $1, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    and %eax, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

Comment: You put your code into the `.data` section. Remove the `.section .data`.